# Quit Algorithm pygame Not working properly

Tags: python, pygame

In this I want the program to close when they hit the quit button but if I enable my `Check_Key_Press()` function, the **`Close()`** function does **not** work however If I comment out the `Check_Key_Press()` function then it works again.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width, height = 500,500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tic Tac Toe(GUI)")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

Tile_dime = 59
Diff = (Tile_dime+1)/2
board_det = [['-',(width/2-3*Diff,height/2-3*Diff)],['-',(width/2-Diff,height/2-3*Diff)],['-',(width/2+Diff,height/2-3*Diff)],
            ['-',(width/2-3*Diff,height/2-Diff)],['-',(width/2-Diff,height/2-Diff)],['-',(width/2+Diff,height/2-Diff)],
            ['-',(width/2-3*Diff,height/2+Diff)],['-',(width/2-Diff,height/2+Diff)],['-',(width/2+Diff,height/2+Diff)]]

def draw_board():
    for i in range(len(board_det)):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, white, [board_det[i][1], (Tile_dime, Tile_dime)])

def Close():
    global run
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

def Check_Key_Press():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pass

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    draw_board()
    Check_Key_Press()
    Close()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get all the messages and remove them from the queue. If `pygame.event.get ()` is called in multiple event loops, only one loop receives the events, but never all loops receive all events. As a result, some events appear to be missed.

Get the events once and use them in multiple loops or pass the list or events to functions and methods where they are handled:

```py
def Close(event_list):
    global run
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```

```py
def Check_Key_Press(event_list):
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            pass
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pass
```

```py
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    draw_board()
    Check_Key_Press(event_list)
    Close(event_list)
    pygame.display.update()
```